# How to choose between same name elements with different attributes

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Consider this XML example

```
  <item>
    <name>"Col"</name>
    <name lang="en">Red</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>"Sha"</name>
    <name lang="en">Square</name>
  </item>
```

I am using XSLT version 1.0
My code is

```
            <xsl:if test="item/name='Col'">
               <xsl:value-of select="'Colour'">
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="item/name/@languageID='en'">
               <xsl:value-of select="item/name@id='en']">
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="item/name='Sha'">
              <xsl:value-of select="'Shape'">
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="item/name/@languageID='en'">
              <xsl:value-of select="item/name@id='en']"> 
            </xsl:if>
```

**My result in HTML is :**

Colour Red

Shape Red

**What I need is :**

Colour Red

Shape Square

How could this be done in xslt? Apologies if this is a simple fix I am new to XSLT

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. I am afraid expressions like `item/name@id='en']` will only give a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something simpler:

**XML**

```
<parent>
    <item>
        <name>Col</name>
        <name lang="en">Red</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Sha</name>
        <name lang="en">Square</name>
    </item>
</parent>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:text>Color: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="item[name='Col']/name[@lang='en']"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;Shape: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="item[name='Sha']/name[@lang='en']"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
Color: Red
Shape: Square
```

---

Note that the values in my XML example contain no quotes.

Comment: Thanks Michael that worked I am very grateful for your help 